# Problems with WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) and Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++

Ok so I'm developing on WSL Linux in Visual Studio Code. I have problems with C++ development. I have installed WSL Remote Connection extension. But when I try to code, and I use #include  I see an error. What's the problem?

Comment: You are going to have to give a lot more information then that if you want any help. Does the file you're trying to include exists on your WSL?

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the [C/C++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) extension installed on WSL.